# How to prevent rounding in Oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to prevent a number from rounding in Oracle Database
I want to prevent a number from rounding in Oracle Database
I want to prevent a number from rounding in Oracle Database
I want to prevent a number from rounding in Oracle Database
price = `14.089` => becomes : `14.09`

In my data base the type of the Column is `DECIMAL`

I want to  get the 3 numbers of the price after the comma.
can anyone hel me how to fix this problem

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    user_tab_columns
WHERE
    table_name = 'GEST_SANTE.PRESTATION_PHARMACIE'
AND column_name = 'PRICE';
```

The result after executing the query:

INSERT INTO ""."" (

```
    "OWNER",
    "TABLE_NAME",
    "COLUMN_NAME",
    "DATA_TYPE",
    "DATA_TYPE_MOD",
    "DATA_TYPE_OWNER",
    "DATA_LENGTH",
    "DATA_PRECISION",
    "DATA_SCALE",
    "NULLABLE",
    "COLUMN_ID",
    "DEFAULT_LENGTH",
    "DATA_DEFAULT",
    "NUM_DISTINCT",
    "LOW_VALUE",
    "HIGH_VALUE",
    "DENSITY",
    "NUM_NULLS",
    "NUM_BUCKETS",
    "LAST_ANALYZED",
    "SAMPLE_SIZE",
    "CHARACTER_SET_NAME",
    "CHAR_COL_DECL_LENGTH",
    "GLOBAL_STATS",
    "USER_STATS",
    "AVG_COL_LEN",
    "CHAR_LENGTH",
    "CHAR_USED",
    "V80_FMT_IMAGE",
    "DATA_UPGRADED",
    "HISTOGRAM"
)
VALUES
    (
        'GEST_SANTE',
        'PRESTATION_PHARMACIE',
        'PRICE',
        'NUMBER',
        NULL,
        NULL,
        '22',
        NULL,
        '3',
        'Y',
        '23',
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        'NO',
        'NO',
        NULL,
        '0',
        NULL,
        'NO',
        'YES',
        'NONE'
    );
```

Comment: If you use `DESCRIBE your_table_name` or `SELECT * FROM user_tab_columns WHERE table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME' and column_name = 'PRICE';` what is the output?

Comment: @MT0 what is user_tab_columns ?

Comment: A view in the data dictionary that describes the columns of the tables owned by the current user.

Comment: @MT0 I test it but nothing appears

Comment: Did you replace `YOUR_TABLE_NAME` with your table name? (in upper-case unless you are using quoted identifiers).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; the `INSERT` statement for your sample data; the statement you are using that is doing the rounding (it is unclear if this is a `SELECT` or an `INSERT` or something else); and a more detailed explanation of the problem. At the moment it is not clear where the problem is because Oracle does not just arbitrarily round numbers.

Comment: If it is from a different schema then use `SELECT * FROM all_tab_columns WHERE owner = 'GEST_SANTE' AND table_name = 'PRESTATION_PHARMACIE' AND column_name = 'PRICE';`

Comment: @MT0 you can find the result in question edited

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues and are conflating the two.

#### Issue 1: Data Storage

You are storing the data in a column with the `DECIMAL(*,3)` data type. This can store, at most, 3 decimal places. It is **IMPOSSIBLE** to store data with more than 3 decimal places and if you attempt it then Oracle will round the input to 3 decimal places because you defined the column as only having 3 decimal places and Oracle is doing exactly what you told it to do.

For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table_name (
  price DECIMAL(*,3)
);
```

Then:

```
INSERT INTO your_table_name (price) VALUES (14.0895);
```

It is **IMPOSSIBLE** to store the exact value as the column is only defined to store 3 decimal places so Oracle will round the number to `14.090` and store that value. Since `14.090` and `14.09` are identical values the database only needs to store `14.09` and the third decimal place is irrelevant as it is `0` and does not need to be stored (and the value is unaffected).

Yes, rounding has occurred but it is because **YOU** defined the column to only store 3 decimal places and tried to insert a number with 4 decimal places so Oracle does its best to store the closest value it can (given the constraints that **YOU** set on the table) and that is through rounding to the appropriate scale.

---

If you want to change the scale of a column so that you can store a greater number of decimal places then you can do that  using:

```sql
ALTER TABLE your_table_name MODIFY (price DECIMAL(*,5));
```

However, it will not change the data already stored in the column; but it would allow you to insert more precise values at a later date.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hTNWUVP2)

---

#### Issue 2: Displaying Data

Oracle does **NOT** store data with any particular formatting. If you want to **display** a value in the database as a number then Oracle will only display the stored digits; it will not automatically format the number to the maximum scale of the column.

For example:

```sql
SELECT price FROM your_table_name;
```

Will output:

> | PRICE |
> | --- |
> | 14.09 |

If you want to **display** it with any particular formatting then **YOU** need to convert the number to a formatted string in the `SELECT` statement and provide the format model to use in the formatting. So to always display 3 decimal places:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(price, 'fm999990.000') AS price
FROM   your_table_name;
```

Will output:

> | PRICE |
> | --- |
> | 14.090 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hq8B0ErV)

Comment: I don't want to add more than 3 numbers after the comma ! in case i have a price 14.15454 so it wil be 14.15454 ! (thats if  i am gonna add DECIMAL places

Comment: @darine If you have stored `14.15454` in a column that has a scale of at least 5 decimal places then Oracle will store that exact number and will **NOT** round it when it displays it. If you have stored it in a column with a scale of less than 5 digits then it **CANNOT** store it to the accuracy that you have provided (because you have told it not to) and will round. You need to explain the problem better as to where the rounding is occurring.

Comment: I stored a price 14.0895 it becomes 14.09 in my database  ! because the scale is 3

Comment: @darine Then, as I said in the answer, change the scale of the column with an `ALTER TABLE` statement. You **CANNOT** store more decimal places in a column than you have told the database are allowed in that column (it is only doing exactly what it has been programmed to do).

Comment: @I didnt work the price still 14.09  i used  this query `ALTER TABLE PRESTATION_PHARMACIE MODIFY (price DECIMAL(*,3));`

Comment: @darine Updated the answer but `14.0895` = `14.090` to 3dp which is identical in value to `14.09`. Oracle does not store formatted numbers, it only stores values and if the least significant digits are `0` then they are irrelevant to the value. If you want to display the value to a set amount of decimal places then use `TO_CHAR` to convert it to a formatted string and specify the decimal places in the format model.

Comment: Can you write the query please !

Comment: @darine The `TO_CHAR` statement is already in the edit to the answer; just put it in your `SELECT` statement in place of where you select the column; it's that simple.

Comment: but this only in select ! will it be modified ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
FLOOR(price * 1000)/1000;
```